# LeetCode: Linked List Cycle

Tags: c#, programming-challenge, linked-list, complexity

## Challenge

https://leetcode.com/explore/interview/card/top-interview-questions-easy/93/linked-list/773/

> Given a linked list, determine if it has a cycle in it.
>
> To represent a cycle in the given linked list, we use an integer pos
>   which represents the position (0-indexed) in the linked list where
>   tail connects to. If pos is -1, then there is no cycle in the linked
>   list.
>
> Example 1:
>
> Input: head = [3,2,0,-4], pos = 1 Output: true Explanation: There is a
>   cycle in the linked list, where tail connects to the second node.
>
> Example 2:
>
> Input: head = [1,2], pos = 0 Output: true Explanation: There is a
>   cycle in the linked list, where tail connects to the first node.
>
> Example 3:
>
> Input: head = [1], pos = -1 Output: false Explanation: There is no
>   cycle in the linked list.

## Follow up

- Can you solve it using \$O(1)\$ (i.e. constant) memory?
- Can you please review about performance?

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace LinkedListQuestions
{
 public class ListNode
    {
        public int val;
        public ListNode next;

        public ListNode(int x)
        {
            val = x;
        }
    }

    [TestClass]
    public class HasCycleTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void HasCycle()
        {
            ListNode head = new ListNode(3);
            head.next = new ListNode(2);
            head.next.next = new ListNode(0);
            head.next.next.next = new ListNode(-4);
            head.next.next.next.next = head.next; //2
            Assert.IsTrue(HasCycleClass.HasCycle(head));
        }

        [TestMethod] public void NoCycle()
        {
            ListNode head = new ListNode(3);
            head.next = new ListNode(2);
            head.next.next = new ListNode(0);
            Assert.IsFalse(HasCycleClass.HasCycle(head));
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void OneItem()
        {
            ListNode head = new ListNode(3);
            Assert.IsFalse(HasCycleClass.HasCycle(head));
        }
    }

    public class HasCycleClass
    {
        public static bool HasCycle(ListNode head)
        {
            if (head == null || head.next == null)
            {
                return false;
            }
            ListNode slow = head.next;
            ListNode fast = head.next.next;
            while(fast!= null)
            {
                if (fast == slow)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    slow = slow.next;
                    if (fast.next == null)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                    fast = fast.next.next;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @dfhwze thanks I added the class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Performance

You have implemented [*Floyd’s Cycle-Finding Algorithm*](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/detect-loop-in-a-linked-list/) which adheres to \$0(1)\$ storage space. An alternative exists [*Brent’s Cycle Detection Algorithm*](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/brents-cycle-detection-algorithm/) which uses the same storage space. Check out this review on [Computer Science SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/63234/why-is-brents-cycle-detection-method-faster-at-finding-a-linked-list-cycle-than) for a comparison. It appears in general, **Brent's algorithm is faster**.

> *According to Brent's paper, the complexity of Floyd's algorithm is between `3max(m,n)` and `3(m+n)`, and that of Brent's is at most
>   `2max(m,n)+n`, which is always better than `3max(m,n)`.*

<sup>courtesy of Yuval Filmus' answer at CS</sup>

#### Style Guidelines

- use `var` to declare a variable, specially when the type can be inferred from code
- use a separate line for declaring attributes on top of members
- use a white space after a method name and the opening parenthesis
- use a white space after the *while* statement
- use white space around operators (`!=`)
- remove redundant nested *else* branches if the *if* branch always performs a *return*

Comment: cool! I didn't know that one

Answer (score 5):

I have some style and organization comments to add to @dfhwze 's previous answer about performance and style.

For `ListNode` class, I would expect `val` and `next` to be named `Value` and `Next`.  I would also rather see them be properties instead of fields.  And for some reason, I am expecting to see a `Previous` property as well.

I see nothing in the exercise description that says you must create your own implementation of a linked list.  Granted, I didn't want to create an account to login to LeetCode.

If the exercise was to create your own linked list, then I would want to see 2 different classes.  One would be the `ListNode` for individual nodes.  The other would be a `LinkedList`, which is a collection of `ListNode`.  Then the method in the `HasCycleClass` could be moved as a member to `LinkedList`.  As you have it, it feels awkward to have the `HasCycleClass` where it is.

If the exercise was simply to create an efficient `HasCycle` method, I would prefer to see you use .NET's [LinkedList](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.linkedlist-1?view=netframework-4.8#methods) and [LinkedListNode](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.linkedlistnode-1?view=netframework-4.8) classes.

In summary, I would really prefer to see something about individual nodes as well as a collection of them.  Your implementation does not make such a distinction.

Comment: Good point about the question not stating clearly that the _Node_ class is predefined. There are indeed faster algorithms if you were able to change the definition and content of that class.